# Web notifications only work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, android, html, firefox, notifications

I have this extremely simple code to test the functionality

```
Notification.requestPermission();
new Notification("DGD");
```

I opened this on 2 devices with Firefox, Chrome, Opera and android browser (7 browsers total), it worked on firefox on both devices and none of the other browsers. Refreshed about a million times and cleared all caches and data. Looking at the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API#Browser_compatibility) it should be working on those browsers (latest versions).

Do you spot where the problem is?

Comment: Perhaps it is a timing issue. The requestPermission requires a user to provide input, and new notification runs before the user has made a choice??

Comment: @CarlK the request is issued once, then you can send notifications as much as you like for the session. It works exactly like this in firefox.